# More convenient auto-completion using ivy

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, ivy

I have the following lines in `~/.emacs`:

```
(require 'counsel)
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") #'counsel-org-tag))
(with-eval-after-load 'org-agenda
  (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") #'counsel-org-tag-agenda))
```

Now, `C-c C-c` provides ivy autocompletion. But the keys for selection are inconvenient `C-M-m` to select en entry and `C-m` to finalize the selection.

I would like to reassign `TAB` intsead of `C-M-m` to select an entry.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In ivy.el, `C-M-m` is assigned to `ivy-call`, and `TAB` is bound to `ivy-partial-or-done`. You can bind `TAB` to `ivy-call` like this:

```
(define-key ivy-minibuffer-map (kbd "TAB") 'ivy-call)
```